# php in_array() usage

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data and I am checking the result by using the in_array() function, yet for some reason it is returning false???

here is the code:

```
    var_dump($result);
    var_dump(in_array("RESULT", $result));
```

and here is the output:

```
array(4) {
  ["TIMESTAMP"]=>
  string(29) "#Wed Jul 20 22:00:32 PDT 2011"
  ["CAUSE"]=>
  string(34) "Username and Password do not match"
  ["RESULT"]=>
  string(5) "FALSE"
  [""]=>
  NULL
}
bool(false)
```

I'm confused???

Comment: Thanks all - I had tested it on a previous array and it turns our "RESULT" was in one of the value keys... I changed the array and confused myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a key not a value. You want to use this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 2):

`in_array()` function checks the values in the array

in your case you could use

```
in_array("RESULT", array_keys($result));
```

or

```
array_key_exists("RESULT", $result);
```

or

```
isset($result["RESULT"]);
```